# jQuery Datatables.net plugin - how to set table's data?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Say I use the following to initialize my table: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html. **How do I later on change the data in the table?**

I need to update the table for a number of reasons (e.g. new data is added, data is deleted, data is updated, data is sorted, etc.). I have methods to do all those, I'm just not sure how to make the table reflect the new data once I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using server-side processing, once the server has the new data, all you need to do is call fnDraw ( http://datatables.net/api#fnDraw ) on your table. That will cause it to make another XHR to the server to get the latest data and draw it.

Comment: Thanks Allan. I'm still not clear about the solution. How do I set the data? In the initialization, I can specify a URL for `sAjaxSource` and the datatable gets populated with the values returned by the URL. What I am trying to do now is update the table data based on certain events (and I want to pass certain parameters to the server, as well). What am I missing?

Comment: Another attempt to explain what I want to do: 1.) an event occurs, 2.) the application becomes aware of certain information, 3.) I want to send that information to the server so I can get the new data I need, and 4.) display that new data in the table.